# If $Ax$ and $Ay$ are linearly independent, then are $x$ and $y$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose matrix $A$ and vectors $x$ and $y$ are conformable for the products $Ax$ and $Ay$.
If $Ax$ and $Ay$ are linearly independent, then are $x$ and $y$ linearly independent?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I'm trying to work around the assumption that linear independence implies Ax = Ay = 0 and nonzero rows of A (in RREF) form linearly independent sets of vectors.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** proof by contradiction.

Suppose that $\alpha x+\beta y=0$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are not equal to 0 simultaneously. Then multiplying  both sides by $A$ from the left, we get:
$$
A(\alpha x+ \beta y)=0 \\
A \cdot \alpha x + A \cdot \beta y=0\\
$$

I bet you can finish it from here.